# An example of a function f whose Cesaro sum series doesn't converge to f in the $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

We know that for a good summability kernel ${k_{n}}$: $k_{n}*f$ converges to f in $L^p$ norm for 1 <= p < $\infty$. But I have trouble finding a counter-example for the case p = $\infty$. Can someone please help me with this one ?

Best regards

Comment: What about Kolmogorov's counter example (for Fourier series...)?

Comment: How one can go then from the divergence of $D_{n}*f$ to that of let's say of $F_{n}*f$ (Fejer kernel) with that example ?

Comment: Oh yes, $D_n$ is not a summability kernel, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question was pretty simple (after giving it some thought): any bounded function on the circle with a set of discontinuities of measure non zero would do the trick !

Comment: ! :) Next, is there a convenient explicit example of such? :)

Comment: The simplest one would be the $2\pi$-periodic function f defined on $[0,2\pi)$ by $f(x) = 0$ if x is irrational and $f(x) = x$ if x is rational. It is in fact discontinuous a.e.

Comment: Ah, ok, I guess that does it! I was overthinking it... apparently. :) Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome ! :)